# mysql query, selecting distinct / max

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count all distinct values from table LDS where `status = 'ok' AND date >= '2012-01-01'` AND if there are multiple identical IDs then only check the one with the newest date: if this id has a status of "ok" then count it.

Table LDS:

```
ID | STATUS  | DATE
1  | ok      | 2012-01-01
2  | bad     | 2012-01-01
1  | bad     | 2012-02-02
3  | ok      | 2012-01-01
4  | ok      | 1999-01-01
```

Result should be "1" (ID 3)

Comment: Note that it shouldn't matter *which* identical id you count.

Comment: Result should be `0` really. Unless you meant `>=` and not `>`

Comment: on my table with many entries I have tried Max(id) FROM LDS WHERE status = 'ok' AND date > '2012-01-01' but that only returns a single ID (with the newest date), not all IDs.

Comment: And if he did mean `>=`... wouldn't the result be "2" (ID:1, ID:3)?

Comment: the primary key is a sequential number not used/shown in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that since you want to count distinct IDs, that it doesn't matter which ID is counted in the case of duplicates, since this doesn't affect the final count:

EDIT: Updated query to exclude any `ID` which has a subsequent `'bad'` status:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lds1.ID)
FROM 
    LDS lds1
    LEFT JOIN LDS lds2
        ON lds1.ID = lds2.ID
        AND lds1.Date < lds2.Date
        AND lds2.Status = 'bad'
WHERE 
    lds1.Date > '2012-01-01'
    AND lds1.Status = 'ok'
    AND lds2.ID IS NUL
```

Comment: using "distinct" returns ID 1 and ID 3, but ID 1 has a new status of "bad" and thus should not be counted at all.

Comment: @user1291842 This only returns a count... a single value.  What query are you running, and what are the results that you're wanting?  Do you want a single count?  A list of all the IDs?

Comment: Thanks for your help - your query is working! I didn't expect it to be so hairy...

Comment: Hi Michael, I now need to make the query even 'hairier' (is that a word?) by adding an additional WHERE clause to be checked prior to your query executing in case this is easy for you. I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055244/mysql-query-nested-where-clauses